# ruby / rails find value from initial range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to find the key of a hash based the value of a key and the next key value?

Easier to understand with an example:

Considering this code:

```rb
h = {
 'size-1': 0,
 'size-2': 50,
 'size-3': 100,
 'size-4': 150,
}

def find_key(value)
  # ...
end

find_key(0) -> 'size-1'
find_key(25) -> 'size-1'
find_key(50) -> 'size-2'
find_key(51) -> 'size-2'
find_key(99) -> 'size-2'
find_key(9999) -> 'size-4'
```

Comment: _"find value from initial range"_ – I understand what you are trying to do, but there is no [range](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Range.html) in your example.

Comment: The example makes sense "next key value" is a bit awkward. Just make sure the original `Hash` is sorted appropriately. Also as an aside I would not recommend using `key: value` notation with those keys because `:'size-1'` makes for an awkward lookup. Instead if the keys are intended to be Strings use Hash rocket notation `'size-1' => 0`

Comment: I agree with you @Stefan any suggestion how to phrase this correctly?

Comment: @engineersmnky this is a diluted example. In reality the value comes from an enum in rails. The keys are symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values define the beginning of each "range", it's easier to search in reverse. To do so, I'd create a reversed array: (I've changed the hash values from symbols to strings according to your expected output)

```
@hash = {
  'size-1' => 0,
  'size-2' => 50,
  'size-3' => 100,
  'size-4' => 150
}

@pairs = @hash.to_a.reverse
#=> [["size-4", 150], ["size-3", 100], ["size-2", 50], ["size-1", 0]]
```

Or via `@pairs = @hash.sort_by { |_k, v| -v }` if your hash isn't already sorted.

The array can now be searched via [`find`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find): (`first` then returns the pair's key)

```
def find_key(value)
  @pairs.find { |_k, v| v <= value }.first
end
```

Which gives:

```
find_key(0)    #=> "size-1"
find_key(25)   #=> "size-1"
find_key(50)   #=> "size-2"
find_key(51)   #=> "size-2"
find_key(99)   #=> "size-2"
find_key(9999) #=> "size-4"
```

If your hash / array is *very* large, you could also consider using a [binary search](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/bsearch_rdoc.html) which works likewise.

Comment: To use a binary search, as Stefan mentioned, and to also allow the hash's key-value pairs to be in any order, one could  use `@hash.sort_by { |_,v| -v }.bsearch { |_,x| x <= v }.first`.